# Batch script to get a list of all files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

I'd like to create a batch script that will create a list of all files in a directory.

So far here's what I have:

```
@echo off

dir c:\users\documents\* /b > filelist.txt
```

This works perfectly with one small hitch. The files I want to get for the list are nestled in multiple user directories which are nestled inside two directories (A-L / M-Z). I can get around the two alphabetical directories easily by just writing two lines for this. However, I'm not sure how to get a list of the files inside of the sub-directories.

BONUS: This is an extra bit that I haven't actually researched yet but thought I'd throw it in there. I'm going to try and get this script to attach the "filelist.txt" to an email and send it out automatically.

EDIT: Forgot a much more important bonus problem.

Here's a really pitiful illustration of the file structure.

[image]

I'd like to be able to have a list that shows the parent directory to the files so that it would show up something like this in the filelist.txt: "A Name\File1.ext"

EDIT: Using `dir /b/s` seems to list all subdirectories, files and gives the full path length. Is there any way to only return a list when there is something in a particular one of the "Name directories"? So if everything but "D Name" is empty, it will only return

```
\D Name\file1.ext
\D Name\file2.ext
```

Comment: Type `dir /?` and read the help. This is a stupid question.

Comment: I apologize on behalf of the other guy. There was no need for hostility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dir` has no code to remove a part of it's output. Therefore you have to parse its output with a `for` loop that does the removal:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "c:\users\documents\"
(
  for /r %%a in (*) do (
    set x=%%a
    echo !x:%cd%=!
  )
)>filelist.txt
popd
```

for sending automatic mails, see our [search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+send+mail), which is well hidden at the top right corner of this site (please don't tell anyone or we will get much less duplicates `;)`).

EDIT for `I don't suppose there's anyway I can limit how far down in subdirectories this works?`
where there is a will, there is a way...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p lv="max Levels deep [0...n]= "
set /a lv+=2
pushd "c:\users\theo\"
(
  for /r %%a in (*.bat) do (
    set x=%%a
    set x=!x:%cd%=!
    for /f "tokens=1,%lv% delims=\" %%b in ("!x!") do if "%%c"=="" echo !x!
  )
)>filelist.txt
popd
```

An input of "0" means "in this folder only, no subfolders"; "2" means "in this folder and its subfolders, max. depth = 2"

The inner `for` checks, if token "%lv%+2" (therefore `set /a lv+=2`) is empty. If yes, the depth is less or equal `%lv%` and the string is shown. If it is not empty, the depth is greater than `%lv%` - no echo.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything different than `dir c:\users\documents\* /b/s > filelist.txt`

I still get a text file that has a list of all the subdirectories, files in those subdirectories, directories in those subdirectories, etc.

Comment: NVM I had something wrong. This works for the most part. I don't suppose there's anyway I can limit how far down in subdirectories this works? Where it only shows 1 or 2 levels down?

Comment: "Yes, we can" - *Barrack Obama*. "Wir schaffen das" (we can do it) - *Angela Merkel* - see my edit, please.

Comment: So replace `set /p lv="max Levels deep [0...n]= "` with `set /p lv="0"`?

Comment: no, with `set /p`, the string after `=` is the prompt. See `set /?` or just try it out. Btw. `0` means "Null levels deep" or in other words: "just this directory without any subfolders"

Answer (score 4):

To search all subdirectories recursively, use the `/s` switch for `dir`.

```
dir c:\users\documents\* /b/s > filelist.txt
```

But there's no way that I'm aware of to send an email from a batchfile without additional programs. If you're not married to the idea of using batchfiles, you can do this easily with PowerShell (and I recommend this method, as PowerShell is the way forward for Microsoft).

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Out-File -FilePath c:\filelist.txt;
Send-MailMessage -To YOURADDRESS -From YOURADDRESS -SmtpServer YOURSMTPHOST -Subject Filelist -Attachments c:\filelist.txt;
```

Comment: Its more a matter of the simplicity of batch. If I can get away with it, it will be much easier to do this if I don't have to install any programs. At least one machine I'll need to do this on is not connected to the internet.

Comment: You don't need to install anything - PowerShell has been part of Windows since Windows 7 (and available all the way back to XP as a separate install). If you have systems that still don't have PowerShell, they're likely past EOL anyway and should be replaced/upgraded anyway. As for the machine not connected to the internet, how were you planning to send the email, regardless of whether it's batch to PS? Batch is dead - PowerShell is how we do modern Windows automation.

Comment: If batch is dead, why did MS add new functionality to cmd.exe in Windows 10?  Everything has its strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @alroc The machine is not connected to the internet but is connected to other machines via intranet.

Comment: @alroc I'm going to at least get the file list working and I may transition to PowerShell later but that would require me to learn how to use PowerShell and I need something at least relatively soon Also, this answer isn't exactly what I'm looking for. It gives me a list of all directories with their full paths but I only need a list that contains any files that exist inside the "Name" directories and those could have full paths (though I'd prefer just the parent directory). Also, I don't need to have the full path of any folders in the "Name" directories.

Comment: @Squashman any updates to batch were likely a byproduct of PowerShell features; but if I'm wrong, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you meant in the EDIT but try this

> dir /A-D /S /B

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I meant either lol. I asked this 5 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Can try:

```
cd "root_dir"
dir /b /s
```

On network can try:

```
pushd "root_dir"
dir /b /s 
popd "root_dir"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).